# EF Core Array, PostgreSQL and SQLite

Tags: c#, postgresql, sqlite, unit-testing

In one of our .NET 7 apps (using EF Core 7) I want to make use of the [PostgreSQL Array Type Mapping](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html) feature and I'm struggling with testing a certain part of the code base.

Please see the following (rather simplified) example:

```cs
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

This works nicely in PostgreSQL, the corresponding data type for `Tags` in PostgreSQL is `text[]` and all the system integration tests (running PostgreSQL in Docker) are passing.

But for the integration tests, we're using an in-memory SQLite database. Since SQLite doesn't seem to support `text[]` as data type, I came up with the following workaround:

```cs
public class TestDbContext : BlogContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(blog => blog.Tags)
            .HasColumnType("text")
            .HasConversion(
                strings => string.Join(",", strings),
                s => s.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    }
}
```

All the integration tests are now working, except for the following class:

```cs
public class BlogService
{
    public BlogService(IDbContextFactory<BlogContext> factory) => _factory = factory;

    public async Task<List<Blog>> FindBlogsWithTag(string tag)
    {
        await using var context = await _factory.CreateDbContextAsync();
        return context.Blogs.Where(blog => blog.Tags.Contains(tag)).ToList();
    }
}
```

The corresponding test fails with:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Blog>()
    .Where(b => b.Tags
        .Contains(__tag_0))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

So my question: how can I make this test pass with SQLite? Is it even possible? Or should I convert the integration test into a system integration test and hereby implicitly switch from SQLite to PostgreSQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked for help in the EF Core repo ([see this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30095)) and got the advice to use a proper PostgreSQL instance, i. e. converting my integration into a system integration test.